# Bash: Native way to check if an entry is one line?

Tags: bash, find, wc

I have a find script that automatically opens a file if just one file is found. The way I currently handle it is doing a word count on the number of lines of the search results. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
if [ "$( cat "$temp" | wc -l | xargs echo )" == "1" ]; then
    edit `cat "$temp"`
fi
```

EDITED - here is the context of the whole script.

```
term="$1"
temp=".aafind.txt"

find src sql common -iname "*$term*" | grep -v 'src/.*lib'  >> "$temp"

if [ ! -s "$temp" ]; then
    echo "ø - including lib..." 1>&2
    find src sql common -iname "*$term*"  >> "$temp"
fi


if [ "$( cat "$temp" | wc -l | xargs echo )" == "1" ]; then
    # just open it in an editor
    edit `cat "$temp"`
else
    # format output
    term_regex=`echo "$term" | sed "s%\*%[^/]*%g" | sed "s%\?%[^/]%g" `
    cat "$temp" | sed -E 's%//+%/%' | grep --color -E -i "$term_regex|$"
fi

rm "$temp"
```

Comment: Is `$temp` a real file containing filenames or a variable with one or more filenames?

Comment: Why do you need `xargs echo`? Are you trying to get rid of the spaces around the output of `wc`? Just get rid of the double quotes around `$(...)`.

Comment: Can you post more of your script? It's not at all clear what `$temp` is or how you go about finding the files.

Comment: Edited. As you can see, I use the temp file to format the output.

Comment: `find ... | grep -v` is silly -- you can just tell find to prune things you don't want. `find src sql common -path 'src/*lib' -prune -o -iname "*$term*" -print` doesn't need any grepping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, given that you are storing these results in the file $temp this is a little easier:

```
[ "$( wc -l < $temp )" -eq 1 ] && edit "$( cat $temp )"
```

Instead of 'cat $temp' you can do '< $temp', but it might take away some readability if you are not very familiar with redirection 8)

Answer (score 7):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, the variable `$temp` contains one or more filenames, one per line, and if there is only one filename it should be edited?

```
[ $(wc -l <<< "$temp") = "1" ] && edit "$temp"
```

If `$temp` is a file containing filenames:

```
[ $(wc -l < "$temp") = "1" ] && edit "$(cat "$temp")"
```

Comment: Consider making the last line `... && edit "$(<"$temp")"` for bash, or `... && edit "$(cat "$temp")"` otherwise -- avoiding the subshell makes things more efficient (given a shell with support), and adding the missing quotes makes things more correct (for filenames containing newlines, wildcard characters, etc). That said, +1.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - thanks, double-quotes added. Every time you post an answer or comment, I learn something new, good job! The `$(<"$temp")` construct makes me a little uneasy, links to good explanation?

Comment: From the "command substitution" section of the bash man page: `The command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).` Roughly, it's a formulation which directly reads from the file without involving a subshell and subprocess involved in using cat in a command substitution, but at the penalty of losing compatibility with POSIX sh.

Answer (score 3):

Several of the results here will read through an entire file, whereas one can stop and have an answer after one line and one character:

```
if { IFS='' read -r result && ! read -n 1 _; } <file; then
  echo "Exactly one line: $result"
else
  echo "Either no valid content at all, or more than one line"
fi
```

For safely reading from `find`, if you have GNU find and bash as your shell, replace `<file` with `< <(find ...)` in the above. Even better, in that case, is to use NUL-delimited names, such that filenames with newlines (yes, they're legal) don't trip you up:

```
if { IFS='' read -r -d '' result && ! read -r -d '' -n 1 _; } \
        < <(find ... -print0); then
    printf 'Exactly one file: %q\n' "$result"
else
    echo "Either no results, or more than one"
fi
```

Comment: your solution is pretty neat, certainly more efficient, but it's not answering the OP's question, which is whether there is a more **easy** way to do it. Your solution is nothing but easy!

Comment: @zmo A "solution" that doesn't cover the corner cases isn't a solution at all, it's a bug waiting to happen. Using `wc -l` to count filenames definitely doesn't cover the corner cases -- a single filename with three newlines in its name would be counted as four separate files! So, no, this isn't easy, but the latter, bash+GNU version is also the only correct solution I've seen given here at all.

Comment: well, the OP wants two cases : 1 line, or not 1 line (which includes 0 lines, 42 lines, no file ...). Good point about the edge case with `\n` in the file name, did not think about that one :-) but what if there is `EOF` in the filename ?

Comment: @zmo the OP specified that what's actually being counted are filenames. POSIX system filenames can't be safely stored in newline-separated streams at all (because you can't tell the difference between one filename containing three newlines and four separate filenames), so the entire question is founded on an invalid premise.

Comment: @zmo ...and by the way, yes, I already cover both the zero and more-than-one cases identically; I'm not clear on why you're reiterating that part of the requirement.

Comment: i like this answer because it does avoid reading the whole file, which no wc based solution could accomplish. Should also be possible to do with something like grep -m 2 . and a grep solution will not need to mess with IFS

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test whether the file is empty or not, `test -s` does that.

```
if [ -s "$temp" ]; then
    edit `cat "$temp"`
fi
```

(A non-empty file by definition contains at least one line. You should find that `wc -l` agrees.)

If you genuinely want a line count of exactly one, then yes, it can be simplified substantially;

```
if [ $( wc -l <"$temp" ) = 1 ]; then
    edit `cat "$temp"`
fi
```

Comment: I am guessing because your original post(s) didn't really answer the question, skipping the 'just one file' bit entirely. The downvote was there before your edits :)

Comment: +1 -- least-silly non-pedantic answer (though I'm a little sketchy on using unquoted expansion to get the name list -- filenames with spaces are a thing that exist, after all, as are glob characters)... actually, damnit, talked myself out of that upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays:

```
 x=($(find . -type f))
 [ "${#x[*]}" -eq 1 ] && echo "just one || echo "many"
```

But you might have problems in case of filenames with whitespace, etc.

Still, something like this would be a native way

Comment: See entry #1 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls -- string-splitting find's output like this is dangerous. (Have filenames containing whitespace? Wildcards? Whitespace surrounding wildcards?)

Comment: Yes, I was just about to add a comment about it but got stuck thinking about solving it with null terminated filenames

Answer (score 1):

no this is the way, though you're making it over-complicated:

```
if [ "`wc -l $temp | cut -d' ' -f1`" = "1" ]; then 
    edit "$temp";
fi
```

what's complicating it is:

- useless use of `cat`,
- unuseful use of `xargs`

and I'm not sure if you really want the `edit`cat $temp`` which is editing the file at the content of $temp

Comment: Redirecting `wc -l <"$temp"`would do away with the `cut` also.

Comment: Using `==` inside of `[ ]` isn't valid POSIX -- POSIX test uses a single `=` for comparison.

Comment: @tripleee good point, but I still prefer it that way. I think it's more readable that way ; @charles-duffy, good point, though I'm always using `==` in my scripts to not get a bad habit when I code in C (and `==` is totally ok in zsh/bash)

Comment: I mean, the OP asked "Is there an **easier** way to do this?, not whether there is a more **efficient** way to do this. His solution is pretty natural, with a few useless stuff, and my solution is the way I'd do it. Readable and simple.

Comment: @zmo better to be in the habit of using `[[ ]]` rather than `[ ]` then -- that way you get more benefits from trading on portability.

Comment: @zmo 'easy' and 'readable' are different things, and `wc -l < "$temp"` is arguably more readable than piping to cut. If you can use a `|`, why discriminate against `<`? ;)

Comment: well, I'm not going to argue over that, because none of `wc -l < "$temp"` or using `wc` is really better, it's only a question of taste. My only point is that I gave the way I'd do it, and neither the most efficient or shortest way to do it!